# C# - How to create an authentication cookie that works in two different servers

Tags: c#, cookies

We have two different projects, which have the same logging credentials, but reside in two different servers.

Authentication has always been managed by cookies, which, then, can correctly let users use any of the websites we have on each server. The thing is, now we're required to allow some users to have access to both servers, and we want them to not need to login twice, once in each server, to access the websites.

The login project is the same in both servers, and the cookie is created the same way, but since they're on different domains, this doesn't work.

I know there are security reasons as to why one cannot set a cookie's domain to a different domain than where the cookie's being created. But is there a workaround to this, or have you seen an alternative to handle this multi-server authentication, given both servers use the same credentials?

Comment: Two different domains are different than just two different servers.   I would recommend looking into oauth 2.0 with a single sign on flow for a recognized pattern that works well.    It is after all what you're using when you login to stackoverflow/stackexchange.

Comment: Is it possible to use federated authentication / SAML / oauth? For example Azure A/D?